# How to realize that the issue cannot be resolved by rx?

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

The reactivex is seemed to be an extremely attractive approach at all. I have two observables with different length and trying to recompose them into one. I've unsuccessfully spent two days for that and I've wondered if any recomposing from two to one observable may be done? This two have all data for the final one.
I deliberately avoid attaching a concrete example. Would like to get some common answer (see the title).

Comment: How do you want them combined? all-the-results-from-one then all-the-results-from-the-other? the results interleaved as they emit? there are operators for both of these (and others) for combining observables however you need.

Comment: I've reverted the question to your original version - can you clarify what you mean by "resolved by Rx"?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of operators for combining the output of two (or more) observables, depending on your use case. Here are a few of the common ones:

**Zip**

Combines multiple observables and combines the output between them, completing when *any* source observable completes:

```
let obs1 = from([0, 1, 2]);
let obs2 = from([a, b, c, d]);
result = obs1.pipe(zip(obs2)).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Output:

```
[0, a], [1, b], [2, c]
```

**Merge**

Combines multiple observables emitting each emission from the source observables as they occur, and continues until *all* source observables have completed:

```
let obs1 = from([0, 1, 2]).pipe(delayTime(100));
let obs2 = from([a, b, c, d]).pipe(delayTime(151));
result = obs1.pipe(merge(obs2)).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Output:

```
0, a, 1, 2, b, c, d
```

**Concat**

Combines multiple observables, emitting all from one until it completes then all from the next:

```
let obs1 = from([0, 1, 2]).pipe(delayTime(100));
let obs2 = from([a, b, c, d]).pipe(delayTime(151));
result = obs1.pipe(concat(obs2)).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Output:

```
0, 1, 2, a, b, c, d
```

Comment: I know about http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#combining. My question was quite different before editing. This is your answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I did not intend to change the meaning of your question at all - can you edit it again to clearly state the question, because I must have misunderstood what you were trying to do @vicpro